# Why does Webmaster tools show duplicate Meta Descriptions for correctly redirected pages?

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, 301-redirect, duplicate-content, meta-tags

I have two pages that show up as having duplicate meta descriptions (and duplicate title tags) on my website.

However, these are old links to a page that has moved location twice so they both redirect to the new location:

- UrlA created.
- (Some months later) UrlA moved to UrlB. UrlA now redirects to UrlB
- (Some months later again) UrlB moved to UrlC. UrlA and UrlB now redirect to UrlC

When I inspect the traffic using fiddler it correctly responds with a 301 and the url is redirected to the new page so I don't understand why Google thinks this is a duplicate.

I have done the same thing with other pages and these do not show up as duplicates.

As requested the urls in question are:

- UrlA - [/TimeandAttendance/CaptureIT.aspx](http://www.time-attendance.co.uk/TimeandAttendance/CaptureIT.aspx)
- UrlB - [/TimeandAttendance/CaptureITTimeandAttendanceSystem/CaptureITITSpecification.aspx](http://www.time-attendance.co.uk/TimeandAttendance/CaptureITTimeandAttendanceSystem/CaptureITITSpecification.aspx)
- UrlC - [/recording-software-system.aspx](http://www.time-attendance.co.uk/recording-software-system.aspx)

Comment: Have you checked your access logs to see if Google has visited these pages since the redirection was put in place.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would like to ask you that why are you using redirection again and again? This is a very bad practice in the eye of Google. May be Google needs some time to understand what is the actual page you want to rank for. When all the link juice will transfer to urlC from urlA and urlB, may be the issue will be resolved.

Found this for your help: http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2288690/How-and-When-to-Use-301-Redirects-vs.-Canonical

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Because we need to change the url of the page. If I didn't redirect then any links would go dead with no indication that it had moved. Google specifically recommend this approach: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

Comment: You are right. But changing URL again and again will make your website specious. I think wait till new link is cached and all old links are removed.

Comment: It has been several months since the second change was made. The first change was over 12 months ago. Other pages changed at the same time are not showing this error.

Comment: Can you share all these URLs?

Comment: I have added the Urls to the question